# PHP MySQL code stops working on new server

Tags: php, mysql

I recently moved my website (currently still in development) from one server to another, and all of a sudden, my PHP code is giving errors. What baffles me is that the new server is owned by the same hosting company, 000 webhost (not the most reliable, but free), and therefore runs the exact same software.

```
<?php
//URL Data Retrieval
$uuid = $_GET['uuid'];

//  MYSQL Server Connection Info
$host="...";        // Host name 
$username="...";            // Mysql username 
$password="...";    // Mysql password 
$db_name="...";         // Database name
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);

// MYSQL Data Retrieval
$sql ="SELECT ProductID, name, description, description2, price, saving FROM product_list WHERE ProductID ='$uuid'";

mysql_select_db($db_name);
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    $error = "Sorry, we could not find this in our database. Please press your browser's back button, and try again.";
  die("");
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $description2 = $row['description2'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $saving = $row['saving'];
} 
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

The code first takes some data from the URL, which works fine, it's the next part that doesn't work.

Here are the errors:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host '10.1.1.24' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/a9790178/public_html/display.php on line 12


PHP Error Message

Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Access denied for user 'a9790178'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a9790178/public_html/display.php on line 17


PHP Error Message

Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/a9790178/public_html/display.php on line 17

PHP Error Message

Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/a9790178/public_html/display.php on line 18
```

And a link to the site: http://discountpenguin.comyr.com/display.php?uuid=1

Comment: i really hope the db connection details above are not the real ones!

Comment: Hope that's not your real login details...
Which errors do you have?

Comment: That's my old password, but don't worry, in the real script I have changed it. I just posted the error messages now.

Comment: @MrYodaylay: it seems you moved script to remote server and database hasn't allowed remote connections. Is your script and DB on one machine?

Comment: @panther, that doesn't help, edits are visible.

Comment: @panther I'm not sure, but the setup process was exactly the same as the old server though. The only difference this time was I uploaded a backup rather than enter all the fields manually.

Comment: did the backup sql script include dbname as a prefix to the tables?
ie: `a9790178_product`.`product_list` etc

Comment: Have you changed to the NEW servers log on parameters?

Comment: @MrYodaylay: The credential you sent to `mysql_connect` are invalid, or remote connections aren't allowed. So, first, check the credentials and if they are okay, check DB server settings, if you can connect to DB remotely.

Comment: Something interesting I just noticed was phpMyAdmin just timed out, so I had to log in again and it said "using password: YES" whereas the error message says "using password: NO". Not sure if this is important...

Comment: @panther I actually have very little control over server settings, but as I have been able to connect to the older server, and, as far as I'm aware, the new server uses exactly the same software, settings, etc., I should be able to connect remotely.